# Get Registry Value C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, registry

I can't seem to get my program to correctly read the registry.  Below is my current code, but I've tried others stuff as well.  It compiles and runs, but it always returns a zero. (I've double checked in the registry, and the value is set at one. "0x000000001(1)"  The key I am trying to access is a **DWord**, and the value should only be a **1 or 0**.  I am running as **admin**, so I have full access privileges. What am I doing wrong?

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey( "SOFTWARE", true );
RegistryKey masterKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Authentication\\LogonUI\\Background");
string value = "";
if( masterKey != null )
{
    value = masterKey.GetValue( "OEMbackground", 2 ).ToString();
}
masterKey.Close();
myLabel.Text=value;
```

Comment: Are you running in an x86 process?

Comment: Your code works on Windows 7 - 32 bit

Comment: good point - if your process is 4-bit, then that path would be: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're running on a 64-bit machine but as a 32-bit process.  That value probably doesn't exist in your 32-bit registry but in the 64-bit registry (that's certainly the case on mine).  You'll probably need to access the 64-bit hive to be able to read that value.  It shouldn't be a problem from a 32-bit process.

```
const string keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background";
using (var hklm64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
using (var key = hklm64.OpenSubKey(keyPath))
{
    var value = (int)key.GetValue("OEMBackground", 2);
}
```

Comment: p.s., You'll need to be running on .NET 4 to get the alternate view as shown here.  If not, you'll probably want to explicitly target x64 to be able to get the value.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. 
Can I do the same thing basically to access Windows\System32 on a 64bit system from 32bit process?

Comment: Sure, I don't see any reason why you couldn't.